# How to add locales to a chrooted system programmatically?

Tags: debian, chroot, debootstrap

I have written a shell script which `debootstrap`s a Debian system into a directory, `chroot`s in there, sets everything up (passwords and SSH keys and so on), and generates a bootable image file from it.

A few additional packages are defined in `debootstrap`s `--include` option. One of them is `locales`.

When the image is booted, trying to run certain programs e.g. `tmux` results in following error message:

```
tmux: invalid LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE or LANG
```

Right now I'm solving this manually by running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` in every booted image. How can I automate this already at `debootstrap` or `chroot` stage, so that the image is correct from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the chroot: configure `/etc/locale.gen` to your liking, then run `locale-gen`.

Comment: I was yet unable to try this, but I read the man page of `locale-gen` and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. It says that in `/etc/locale.gen` `every line that is not empty and does not begin with a # is treated as a locale definition that is to be built.` Would `de_AT.UTF-8` qualifiy as correct _locale definition_ as per the syntax? (I'm at the moment unable to simply try it myself.)

Comment: @Multisync: Yes, it is, see the file, which by default is full of commented lines. Refer to the man page of `locale.gen` as well.